# How to pass a complex parameter to a component in razor markup

Tags: blazor

```
<MyComponent Height="3">
    <SensorDataProperty>
        <SensorData Speed="300" Throughput="5"/> 
    </SensorDataProperty>
</MyComponent>

public class MyComponent 
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public SensorData SensorDataProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SensorData
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Throughput { get; set; }

}
```

How do I pass a complex parameter to my component in razor markup as shown in the pseudo code above?
SensorData will not be rendered.  I am aware of Blazor's binding functionality however my question does not relate to binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it before answer, but I think that [template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#template-parameters) is your way.

Something like:

```cs
@typeparam TItem  (<== in case you have multiple items of something)

your HTML template...

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<SensorData> SensorDataProperty { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out it is [not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35771)